# How does Hilt keep a instance when i use @Singleton in ViewModelComponent

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I know it is good to use @Singleton provider when we share between multiple ViewModels and that do not need to different instances of provided object. But i do not find anything about how does the removing instance process deal with multiple ViewModels ?

Lets say,

SharedRepository is provided by AViewModel
SharedRepository is provided by BViewModel

In this case, does dagger hilt the instance until both ViewModel has been destroyed ?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object DataModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAddressRepository(addressRemoteDataSource: AddressRemoteDataSource, @IoDispatcher dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher): AddressRepository {
        return AddressRepositoryImpl(addressRemoteDataSource, dispatcher)
    }
}
```